# iOS-Charts Reset offset in xAxis

Tags: ios, ios-charts

I am using iOS-Charts to show a bar chart.

**I drag the chart to this position:**

[image: Screen Shot]

**Now I need to reset the position of xAxis by code like following:**

[image: Screen Shot]

But I didn't find an API to reset it. How can I reset xAxis by code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to solve it.

```
let srcMatrix: CGAffineTransform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 0)
barChartView.viewPortHandler.refresh(newMatrix: srcMatrix, chart: barChartView invalidate: true)
```